# Dropping table from DB using Java

Tags: java, jdbc

How to drop the table from the database if any of threads still using the table.
I have a requirement of Force drop of table.
i am using some or mess of threads so i need to drop forcefully.
Is any way to drop the table.

Comment: It may depends on your database. Which on is it ? If there is a lock on some data of your table, I doubt you can drop it.

Comment: What database is this? You'll probably need to do a cascade delete.